# Select data from two tables with no join condition, t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd appreciate if someone could help.
I have two tables that have no relationship:

Table_1

```
ID    NAME    VALUE
1     abc     10
2     def     20
3     def     20
```

Table_2

```
   ID2    NAME2    VALUE2
    5     ghi     30
    6     gkl     40
```

I want to have a select statement that would show the data from both tables like this:

```
   ID    NAME    VALUE  ID2   NAME2   VALUE2
    1     abc     10    5     ghi     30
    2     def     20    6     gkl     40
    3     def     20
```

The point is to show data of each record in one row, the table can look like:

```
 ID    NAME    VALUE  ID2   NAME2   VALUE2
                      5     ghi     30
                      6     gkl     40
```

If `Table_1` has no records. Same is true for `Table_2`.
I tried to use cross join, but then the data will repeat.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any relationship between rows in Table_1 and rows in Table_2? I mean how I can determine that a row with ID 1 should be next to the row with ID 5 as in your example?

Comment: Only by row_number()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `join` condition.  In this case, by using `row_number()` to add a sequential number on each side.  Then `full outer join` to get all the records:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.value, t2.id as id2, t2.name as name2, t2.value as value2
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from table_1 t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from table_2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Comment: The table_2 table doesn't have the id column, there is the id2 column

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with Table_1(ID, NAME, VALUE) as (
  select 1, 'abc', 10 union all
  select 2, 'def', 20 union all
  select 3, 'def', 20
), Table_2(ID2, NAME2, VALUE2) as (
  select 5, 'ghi', 30 union all
  select 6, 'gkl', 40
), prep_table_1 (ID, NAME, VALUE, rn) as (
  select id, name, value, row_number() over(order by id)
    from table_1
), prep_table_2 (ID2, NAME2, VALUE2, rn) as (
  select id2, name2, value2, row_number() over(order by id2)
    from table_2
)
select t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.VALUE, t2.ID2, t2.NAME2, t2.VALUE2
  from prep_table_1 t1
  full outer join prep_table_2 t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39399)

Answer (score 0):

This also works

select * from Table_1,Table_2

Comment: this is a cross join.